# Signifying "all" when pulling data from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array that contains several numbered entries that are all identical, like this:

```
var levels = new Object;
levels = {
    0:{
        name: "xxx1",
        ratesBR: {
            stone: 1,
            wood: 5,
            copper: 0,
        }
        ratesFS: {
            food: 10,
            water: 10,
            sacrifice: 0,
        }
    }
    1:{
        name:"xxx2",
        ratesBR: {
            stone: 1,
            wood: 5,
            copper: 0,
        }
        ratesFS: {
            food: 10,
            water: 10,
            sacrifice: 0,
        }
    }
}
```

So my question is this, say I want to check that 'stone' is greater than or equal to 1 in all the "levels" (0,1, etc.) using

```
if levels.XX.ratesBR.wood >= 1
```

but in place of XX, I am wondering what I can use to signify "all" I have looked around and the closest I came was the every() function but I don't think that is what I am looking for. I have no idea what the "all" signifier would even be called, so I am turning to Y'all for a direction to go in. Thanks.

Comment: That's not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I have an array...

That's not an array, it's a non-array object. It just has property names `"0"`, `"1"`, etc. (yes, they're strings even though they've been written as numbers).

> and the closest I came was the every() function but I don't think that is what I am looking for.

It is, but it's slightly awkward to apply it to a non-array object. We can do so by using `Object.keys` to get the object's keys, and then using `every` on that.

In ES5, you'd do it like this:

```
if (Object.keys(levels).every(function(key) { return levels[key].ratesBR.wood >= 1; })) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var levels = {
  0: {
    name: "xxx1",
    //lifeStage: 
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 1,
      wood: 5,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  },
  1: {
    name: "xxx2",
    //lifeStage:
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 2,
      wood: 0,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  }
};

if (Object.keys(levels).every(function(key) { return levels[key].ratesBR.wood >= 1; })) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

In ES2015+, an arrow function can make it more concise:

```
if (Object.keys(levels).every(key => levels[key].ratesBR.wood >= 1)) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var levels = {
  0: {
    name: "xxx1",
    //lifeStage: 
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 1,
      wood: 5,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  },
  1: {
    name: "xxx2",
    //lifeStage:
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 2,
      wood: 0,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  }
};

if (Object.keys(levels).every(key => levels[key].ratesBR.wood >= 1)) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

---

If `levels` really were an array (which I'd recommend), you'd just use `every` directly on it:

```
// IF `levels` WERE AN ARRAY
if (levels.every(entry => entry.ratesBR.wood >= 1)) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

Live Example:

```js
var levels = [
  {
    name: "xxx1",
    //lifeStage: 
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 1,
      wood: 5,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  },
  {
    name: "xxx2",
    //lifeStage:
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 2,
      wood: 0,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
      food: 10,
      water: 10,
      sacrifice: 0
    }
  }
];

if (levels.every(entry => entry.ratesBR.wood >= 1)) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

And the ES5 version:

```
// IF `levels` WERE AN ARRAY
if (levels.every(function(entry) { return entry.ratesBR.wood >= 1; })) {
    console.log("All are >= 1");
} else {
    // No, at least one isn't
    console.log("At least one isn't >= 1");
}
```

Comment: I saw it, and sorry I forgot to add the var levels = new Object.

Comment: @Akmedrah: That doesn't change the answer. I assumed the variable was declared, and the `= new Object` part of that statement is thrown away, as you overwrite the value in `levels` in the very next statement (with an object created via an object initializer).

Answer (score -1):

You could do something like this:

```
var levels = {
  0:{
    name: "xxx1",
    //lifeStage: 
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 1,
      wood: 5,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
    food: 10,
    water: 10,
    sacrifice: 0
  }
},
1:{
    name: "xxx1",
    //lifeStage: 
    ratesBR: {
      stone: 1,
      wood: 5,
      copper: 0
    },
    ratesFS: {
    food: 10,
    water: 10,
    sacrifice: 0
  }
}
}

var array = $.map(levels, function(value, index) {
    return [value];
});
for(var i =0; i < array.length; i++){
  console.log(array[i].ratesBR.stone);
}
```

Comment: There is no jQuery tag on the question, nor is jQuery used anywhere within it. jQuery answers to non-jQuery questions are not useful.

Comment: Separately: You're creating an array of arrays, but then not using the resulting array correctly; the code would fail with trying to read `ratesBR` of `undefined`.